# Unsolved Reference ifNull and 'return' is not allowed here when doing React Native Android build process

Tags: android, react-native, expo

So I got the following error message:

```
> Task :expo-image-picker:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (25, 36): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (131, 39): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (133, 7): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (138, 71): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (140, 7): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (193, 7): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (195, 7): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (200, 39): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (202, 7): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (325, 8): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (327, 9): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (376, 8): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (378, 9): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (381, 46): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.kt: (383, 7): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerOptions.kt: (4, 36): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerOptions.kt: (40, 9): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerOptions.kt: (42, 9): 'return' is not allowed here
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerUtils.kt: (11, 36): Unresolved reference: ifNull
e: /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/MyApp/Frontend/Expo/node_modules/expo-image-picker/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imagepicker/ImagePickerUtils.kt: (32, 39): Unresolved reference: ifNull
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have not been able to solve it, despite looking absolutely everywhere.

I've tried changing my AndroidManifest.xml, I've tried gradle clean, I've tried deleting my .gradle file, I have this adding this:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to my gradle.properties

And this

```
dexOptions {
   javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
}
```

to my build.gradle

I also tried:

```
./gradlew -stop
```

This happened after I updated expo-image-picker from 11.0.3 to 12.0.2

What exactly is going on here, and how do I fix it?